# How can I draw 500 million triangles with OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, performance, vbo

I am a beginner. I have a problem with my frame rate. I am trying to see my GPUs maximum performance with using VBO. I saw that everybody says a GPU can draw 1 billion triangles (so 3 billion vertices) with VBO easily, is it right? If it is right, then why am I getting 37 FPS at only 8 million triangles (24 million vertices)?

I am not using a shader and I don't know how to use it.

My GPU is (amd radeon hd 6870).

When drawing 20k triangles, the frame rate is 6000, when drawing 8 million triangles, the frame rate is 37 and CPU usage 1%. I don't think the CPU is the bottleneck..

My code is like this:

I create in header file

```
GLuint terrainVBO;
```

I made an `init()` function:

```
glGenBuffers(1,&terrainVBO);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,terrainVBO);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,terrainVertices.size()*sizeof(terrainVec),&terrainVertices[0],GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

and draw in my main loop:

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,terrainVBO);
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glVertexPointer(3,GL_FLOAT,3*sizeof(float),0);

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES,0,terrainVertices.size());

glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,0);
```

Summary: How can I draw 500-600 millions triangles (1.5 billion vertices) with a good frame rate? I could only draw 8 million triangles.

Comment: Why do you need 500 million? Not even AAA games use that much

Comment: 1200000000 vs. 296000000 triangles a second. Sounds about right considering the additional overhead of handling that much data. I guess the answer is "you can't".

Comment: Yes, you can't, even with the newest GPUs I think you can get at most 10 millions. Search on YouTube particles simulations and you'll get an idea. (With a gtx 780 I could reach 6 millions if I remember right, but I think the bottleneck was the updating of particles CPU side, with a compute shader I think you can get something more

Comment: Therefore is average value (8 million triangles= 37 fps ) ? is it normal ? and thank you for your comments guys

Comment: @EmreKaya Well, you shouldn't expect anything crazy with the naive approach. You should consider yourself lucky you are getting anything rendered at all with no shader. It is just unreasonable to expect to copy over that much data to the GPU and expect it to handle it fast. To get anything special, you will need to learn shaders, specifically the more advanced ones, so you can generate triangles in flight.

Comment: @rationalcoder my purpose is not getting anything special i just want to learn what is average value example if i use same triangles with shaders will i get more fps and how much or fps will not change ? dont important image quality can you just say me fps sort i am thinking VBO with no shader > VBO with shader > display list > vertex array > immediate mode my guess is true ? i know using vbo with shader image quality should be better others but when figures are considered, my sort is true ? sorry for bad english :)

Comment: @EmreKaya My point was that "VBO with no shader" is not really I thing as far as I know. Getting triangles to be drawn without a simple pass through shader shouldn't be possible without the fixed function pipeline. It's best if you just use the core profile and forget the fixed-function pipeline exists. There are only two major techniques: VAO (A default one is provided if you don't use them explicitly) + VBOs + shaders > immediate mode. Display lists are just an optimization for drawing with static data when using immediate mode.

Comment: @EmreKaya I ran out of space on the last comment, but your comparison should be between using a naive pass though shader, explicitly copying over data like you are now, and using a geometry shader to generate triangles. Also, there isn't really any average value for triangles to FPS, because there too many factors to consider. Nobody that I know of has made a game that solely consists of a massive number of otherwise unprocessed triangles.

Answer (score 2):

I just don't know what you want to draw.
If you want to draw one object with that many triangles, you probably want to use [indexed rendering](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/intermediate-tutorials/tutorial-9-vbo-indexing/). But if you want to draw that many independent triangles you should learn how to use [instanced rendering](https://learnopengl.com/#!Advanced-OpenGL/Instancing) because it's good for drawing many similar objects.
Maybe those two techniques can boost your performance. But as already said, it is ridiculous to draw that many triangles/vertices at once.